# Select which value is present the most number of times in column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Follow is sample table

```
Project | Reporter | Fixer  | Status    
--------+----------+--------+--------
P1      | Fernando | Janith | closed   
P1      | hasitha  | Nimna  | Fixed    
p1      | Amal     | Nimna  | Fixed    
P2      | Nimal    | Amal   | Fixed    
P3      | Kamal    | Nimal  | Fixed    
P4      | Andrew   | Amal   | Fixed
```

What I want is Project name, Status count for each project, count of each project's Status 'Fixed', count of project's Status 'Closed' and **Fixer who fixed most number of Projects.**

except the Bold part I was able to get others using following query

```
SELECT Project
    ,count(Project) AS ProjectCount
    ,count(CASE STATUS
            WHEN 'Fixed'
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS Fixed
    ,count(CASE STATUS
            WHEN 'Closed'
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS Closed
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Project;
```

Output I need

```
Project, ProjectCount, Fixed, Closed, Fixcer    
P1,          3,          2,     1,     Nimna
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?  What about your current code doesn't work?

Comment: why you output doesnt have p2, p3, and p4?

Comment: I assume you want something like SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl WHERE STATUS = 'Fixed' GROUP BY Fixer.

Comment: Do you want a row of output for each project or just one most row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is will select the first fixer with most appear on the project but doesnt handle ties. So you should provide a rule to handle ties.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73d18/7)**

```
SELECT Project
    ,count(Project) AS ProjectCount
    ,count(CASE STATUS
            WHEN 'Fixed'
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS Fixed
    ,count(CASE STATUS
            WHEN 'Closed'
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS Closed
    , (SELECT fixer
       FROM Table1 B
       WHERE A.`Project` = B.`Project`
       GROUP BY fixer
       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
       LIMIT 1
      ) as Fixer
FROM TABLE1 A
GROUP BY Project;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Project | ProjectCount | Fixed | Closed | Fixer |
|---------|--------------|-------|--------|-------|
|      P1 |            3 |     2 |      1 | Nimna |
|      P2 |            1 |     1 |      0 |  Amal |
|      P3 |            1 |     1 |      0 | Nimal |
|      P4 |            1 |     1 |      0 |  Amal |
```

Comment: Thanks Juan exactly what I need

Comment: As I say just be carefull because if two Fixer has same count will return a random fixer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the info only for the project with most times, use this query:

```
SELECT 
    P1.Project, 
    COUNT(*) ProjectCount, 
    SUM( P1.Status = 'Fixed' ) Fixed, 
    SUM( P1.Status = 'Closed' ) Closed, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
      FROM Project P2
      WHERE P1.Project = P2.Project AND P2.Status = 'Fixed'
      GROUP BY P2.Fixer
      ORDER BY cnt DESC
      LIMIT 1 )
FROM Project P1
GROUP BY P1.Project;
```

If you want info for all projects, use this one:

```
SELECT 
    P1.Project, 
    COUNT(*) ProjectCount, 
    SUM( P1.Status = 'Fixed' ) Fixed, 
    SUM( P1.Status = 'Closed' ) Closed, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
      FROM Project P2
      WHERE P1.Project = P2.Project AND P2.Status = 'Fixed'
      GROUP BY P2.Fixer
      ORDER BY cnt DESC
      LIMIT 1 )
FROM Project P1
GROUP BY P1.Project
ORDER BY ProjectCount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```